# Deleting folder no longer causes asp.net application to restart in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, application-restart

In asp.net 2, deleting a folder will cause the application to restart. But today I found that this behavior no longer existed in asp.net 4? I can't find any information about this. Can anybody tell me if this is true? If yes, that's awesome! I hate this application restart behavior in asp.net 2. You can try this:

Debug the following code in asp.net webforms (.net 3.5) and you'll catch the ThreadAbortException. But when you debug it in asp.net webforms (.net 4), you won't catch any exception; everything is fine. I think the reason why I got ThreadAbortException is that I deleted a directory in the thread. Then application restarted, and then the thread got aborted. (Environment: Win8, VS2012, IIS Express)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var folderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data\\Test");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "test.txt");

            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
            }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello");

            try
            {
                var loop = 100;

                while (loop > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    loop++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
        });
        thread.Start();

        Response.Write("Running");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As fas i I can see there is not difference between 3.0 and 4.0, the following action will cause the app to restart:

> Application Restarts
>
> Modifying the source code of your Web application will cause ASP.NET
>   to recompile source files into assemblies. When you modify the
>   top-level items in your application, all other assemblies in the
>   application that reference the top-level assemblies are recompiled as
>   well.
>
> In addition, modifying, adding, or deleting certain types of files
>   within the application's known folders will cause the application to
>   restart. The following actions will cause an application restart: •
>   Adding, modifying, or deleting assemblies from the application's Bin
>   folder.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting localization resources from the
>   App_GlobalResources or App_LocalResources folders.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting the application's Global.asax
>   file.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting source code files in the App_Code
>   directory.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting Profile configuration.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting Web service references in the
>   App_WebReferences directory.
>
> •    Adding, modifying, or deleting the application's Web.config file.

[MSDN 3.0 ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN 4.0 ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So I guess it depends on `which` folder you delete in the appliction directory.

Comment: Could you try my code (just added it to the post). I did get different result in asp.net 2 and asp.net 4. Thanks!

Comment: @Mouhong Lin I do not think your app is restarting, however what are the directory paths (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) in 3.5 and 4.0?

Comment: I do fix this by disable the File Change Notification in app start (my project is using 3.5). So I think it's caused by restarting. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is same in 3.5 and 4.0, pointing to the website directory